# Is it possible to connect to local Google Cloud Datastore with DatastoreService using Endpoints?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to connect to my local Google Cloud Datastore using Endpoints (java), and I would prefer to access the db with a DatastoreService object. The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/devserver) does not say anything about this.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: I think I don't understand the question since the two (endpoints, datastore)  are unrelated. You can use them independently and in combination, why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: @konqi I am running Google Endpoints in a local "sandbox" environment and I would like to know if it is possible to connect/read/write to my local Google Cloud Datastore using the DatastoreService class from Endpoints.

Comment: If by sandbox you mean the app engine dev server then yes. If not you could use the unit test stubs for the datastore (see: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Java_Writing_Datastore_and_memcache_tests).

Comment: I did'n realise before now, that there were other ways to connect to Datastore than using DatastoreService. I am now using [Objectify](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Concepts) which solved all my problems.

Comment: Objectify is more of a wrapper around the datastore. I use it a lot. I would not have guessed though that this is what you were looking for.